# Pull out valueForKeys of an inner NSMutableDictionary iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-coding

Ok I get and store a Json feed to an array called jsonArray. I then loop over the jsonArray pulling out the array keys and storing them as strings. I then add those strings to an inner dictionary called innerDict, I then add that dictionary to the info dictionary with the key thePostCode using the below. So basically innerDict is stored inside infoDict.

```
-(void)pointInfo{

infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++) {

innerDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

info = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"inf"];
thePostCode = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"pc"];
mail = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"mail"];
url = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"url"];
type = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"items"];

[innerDict setObject:type forKey:@"Items"];
[innerDict setObject:info forKey:@"Info"];
[innerDict setObject:mail forKey:@"Mail"];
[innerDict setObject:url forKey:@"Url"];

[infoDict setObject:innerDict forKey:thePostCode];

}
```

the output of infoDict looks like this:

```
infoDict is {
"ME14 4NN" =     {
    Info = "";
    Items = 4;
    Mail = "";
    Url = "";
};
"ME15 6LG" =     {
    Info = af;
    Items = "0,6,9";
    Mail = "";
    Url = "";
};
"ME15 6YE" =     {
    Info = "";
    Items = "4,5,6,7,11";
    Mail = "";
    Url = "";
};
}
```

Now what I want to do is get the values of the innerDict object i.e "ME15 6YE" above and use that as the query to pull out the associated data for Info, Items, Mail and Url keys. I have been staring at my screen for a few hours but I am just not getting it.

I can pull out the last object of the inner dict using the below however I would like to grab all the values associated with a particular postcode which would be the innerDict key. Completely brain fried at the moment!

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in infoDict) {

    NSLog(@"URL %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Url"]);
    NSLog(@"MAIL %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Mail"]);
    NSLog(@"ITEMS %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Items"]);
    NSLog(@"ITEMS %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Info"]);

}
```

Comment: One option would be a create a custom object to store your data and then store instances of these objects in a dictionary, keyed on that (postcode?) key value.  In other words create a Model which can be re-used throughout your project.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am sure there is something simple I can add to the last mentioned for loop to pull out the values for a particular postCode but I just cant think at the moment..

Comment: OK, I've provided an answer, but it seems too obvious to be correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct inner dictionary, use `objectForKey`:

```
NSDictionary *innerDict = [infoDict objectForKey:@"ME15 6YE"];
NSLog(@"Url %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Url"]);
NSLog(@"Mail %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Mail"]);
NSLog(@"Items %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Items"]);
NSLog(@"Info %@", [innerDict objectForKey:@"Info"]);
```

Comment: Oh dear yes it was very simple lol spent too long being hung up on the fact it was an inner dictionary...thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I think this should answer your questions.

You're using **dictionary** in the for loop, but trying to access it via **innerDict**. Change it to:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in infoDict) {
    NSLog(@"URL %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"Url"]);
    NSLog(@"MAIL %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"Mail"]);
    NSLog(@"ITEMS %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"Items"]);
    NSLog(@"ITEMS %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"Info"]);
}
```

Or, for a single one,

```
NSMutableDictionary *inner = [infoDict objectForKey:@"POST CODE HERE"];
NSLog(@"URL %@", [inner objectForKey:@"Url"]);
NSLog(@"MAIL %@", [inner objectForKey:@"Mail"]);
NSLog(@"ITEMS %@", [inner objectForKey:@"Items"]);
NSLog(@"ITEMS %@", [inner objectForKey:@"Info"]);
```

Comment: Thanks mate your answers are also correct however trojanfoe was there first I will upvote you!